# What does brew tap mean?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Sometimes I see articles saying command of `brew tap` before `brew install` something. I am wondering what does `tap` mean? And why must I run `tap` before `install`?

Comment: It is to access other repositories that are not included in Homebrew's master repository. You must tap before installing a package that is from another repository. You can see all current taps with `brew tap`.

Comment: The other comment is correct, but by way of explanation, when you *tap* a resource, you gain access to it. But it is also another beer/brewing reference (as is `homebrew`) because when you *tap* a keg of beer you are essentially knocking a valve into it to *"gain access to the beer"*.

Comment: If you are confused by the multitude of beer-related verbs, as I am, there is a [glossary](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md#homebrew-terminology).

Comment: The only good thing about brew's name is that it's short

Comment: Why is this on StackOverflow? It's not about writing code -- [unix.se] or [apple.se] are more obviously appropriate.

Comment: it just "links" to another repository.  they should have called it "link" or "connect to repository", but they wanted to be cute  :)   it's "tap" in the sense of a verb .. "tap in to".

Comment: for people coming from ubuntu (linux) this is equivalent to external PPA

Answer (score 412, accepted):

The tap command allows Homebrew to **tap into** another repository of formulae. Once you've done this you've expanded your options of installable software.

These additional Git repos (inside `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps`) describe sets of package formulae that are available for installation.

E.g.

```
brew tap                     # list tapped repositories
brew tap <tapname>           # add tap
brew untap <tapname>         # remove a tap
```

Comment: `brew cask` seems to add the `caskroom/cask` repo. Is that a shortcut and essentially the same as `brew tap caskroom/cask` ?

Comment: So this means `brew tap` will add an unofficial, third-party repository?

Comment: how do you list the formulae from a certain tap?

Comment: For me the path was /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps

Comment: "..repository of formulae", what's meaning of formulae ?

Comment: @vikramvi a package definition written in Ruby, essentially a ruby file that can be created by `brew create <URL>` in which the URL is a zip/tarball. Those ruby files use the Formula API. it provides instructions and metadata for Homebrew to install a piece of software. and they all are Formula class.

Answer (score 56):

`brew tap` adds more repos to the list of formulae that brew tracks, updates, and installs from

`brew tap <user>/<repo>` makes a shallow clone of the repository at https://github.com/user/homebrew-repo. Note that `brew tap` prefixes the repo name with "homebrew-". After that, brew will be able to work on those formulae as if they were in Homebrew's canonical repository

The full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Taps.md) with all the available options.

Answer (score 56):

### **Homebrew Terminology**:

- `package` ≡ `formula` ≡ `ruby file`: this typically deals with command line (CLI) software
- `bottle`: binary program already built for some OS (macOS montery, macOS big_sur, arm64_monterey, arm64_big_sur, catalina, x86_64_linux) (configurations and `make` is already done)
- `casks`: GUI program or font; this is an extension of homebrew that allows us to install MacOS native applications like: Google Chrome (`brew cask install google-chrome`), iTerm (`" " iterm2`), Visual Studio Code (`" " visual-studio-code`), etc. As well as install fonts: Roboto[ Mono] (`" " font-roboto`/`" " font-roboto-mono`), Latin Modern (`" " font-latin-modern`), etc.
- `taps`: [Github|Gitlab|...] repositories containing additional [formulas for downloading] packages that are not standard, i.e not incorporated into the official homebrew repository containing all [formulas for downloadable] packages.

  > "taps" allow you to extend the list of packages that you can install via homebrew. by "tapping" a repository you download (literally `git clone`) the repository locally. the repository wil contain ruby files (formulas) that tell homebrew how to download, configure, build, install, etc, an additional list of packages. then when you do `brew install X`, `brew` will scan through the official/standard homebrew repositories that you have locally, won't find a formula for `X`, then it will scan through your "taps" and if it finds a formula for `X`, will run it (the formula is a `ruby` file).

---

- Packages are installed into `/usr/local/Cellar/<package>` with symlinks into `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`, etc.
- Homebrew core repo formulae:

  - downloaded to `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/formula`

---

You can find any package at: https://formulae.brew.sh/

Comment: Lovely explaination. Thanks